# Перенос на новую строку если первая строка уже существует

Tags: html, css, html5

```html
<div class="grid__item grid__item--featured-collections small--one-half medium-up--one-fifth">
  <div class="grid-view-item">
    <a class="grid-view-item__link" href="/'.$row[" type_tovara "].'/'.$row["products_id "].'-'.ftranslite($row["title "]).'/">
      <div class="small--hide" style="margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["top_sales"].'</div>
      <div class="site-header__menu" style="margin-top: 22px; margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["top_sales"].'</div>
      <div class="small--hide" style="margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["under_order"].'</div>
      <div class="small--hide" style="margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["novelty"].'</div>
      <img class="grid-view-item__image" src="'.$img_path.'">
      <div class="h4 grid-view-item__title">'.$row["title"].'</div>
      <div class="grid-view-item__meta">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Regular price</span>
        <span class="product-price__price">'.group_numerals($row["price"]).' грн</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Отображается вот так, видно что слово "Новинка" налезла сверху на другую этикетку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо чтобы последующие этикетки если есть то чтобы они были с новой строки, как не пытался сделать, не получается, всегда съезжают этикетки вместе с фоткой кофты...

Стили этикеток прикрепляю:

```css
.plus1{border:1px solid #0095EB;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);color:#0095EB;
 z-index:3;border-radius:3px;padding:0px 4px 2px 4px;position:absolute;margin-left:35px;margin-top:-25px;font-size:12px;float:left;}
 
.plus2{border:1px solid #0095EB;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);color:#0095EB;
 z-index:3;border-radius:3px;padding:0px 4px 2px 4px;position:absolute;margin-left:35px;margin-top:-25px;font-size:12px;float:left;}
 
.plus3{border:1px solid #0095EB;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);color:#0095EB;
 z-index:3;border-radius:3px;padding:0px 4px 2px 4px;position:absolute;margin-left:35px;margin-top:-25px;font-size:12px;float:left;}
```

Сами этикетки:

```html
<div class="plus2">Под заказ</div>
<div class="plus3">Новинка</div>
<div class="plus4">Топ</div>
```

Пример как должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Задайте нужному элементу такие стили

```
.item {
     display: block;
    }
```

Comment: не совсем понял как реализовать...

Comment: укажите свойство display: block элементу, который надо перенести на следующую строку

Comment: мол вот так вот?       <div class="small--hide" style="margin-left: -35px;">'.$row["top_sales"].'</div>
     
      
      <div class="small--hide" style="margin-left: -35px;display: block;">'.$row["under_order"].'</div> - не срабатывает